# PHP & Dropbox API - Error Fatal error: Uncaught Dropbox\Exception_BadRequest: HTTP status 400 {"error": "v1_retired"}

Tags: php, composer-php, dropbox, dropbox-api

I was having an error when i put `$client->getAccountInfo();` and error is showing. **Error Fatal error: Uncaught Dropbox\Exception_BadRequest: HTTP status 400 {"error": "v1_retired"}**

here is my composer

```
{
  "require": {
    "dropbox/dropbox-sdk": "1.1.*"
  }
}
```

I know that the problem was the dropbox-sdk version but when I change the `1.1.*` to `2.*` nthing is installed in the composer. help please how can I solve this error and if possible how can i install the v2 ?

Comment: The problem is indeed that you're using an old version.. Can you be more specific about 2.x not installing correctly? What are you seeing exactly

Comment: @Evert It cannot define version 2, is there any way on how can i install the v2 sir?

Comment: Take a look here: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/communitysdks I think the package you are using has never been updated for the new API. You need to find an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

[The `v1_retired` error does indicate that you're calling the retired Dropbox API v1](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2017/09/api-v1-shutdown-details/). You should [use Dropbox API v2](https://www.dropbox.com/developers) instead.

Nothing is installed when you specify '2.*' for that library, because [there is no v2 version of it](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-php/releases).

Dropbox doesn't offer an official PHP SDK for Dropbox API v2, but you can use [a third party library](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/communitysdks), or you can call [the HTTPS endpoints themselves](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation).